# Is it possible to get both touch screen and touch pad feature for Notability as such Apple Laptops are not touchscreen?

Tags: ipad, trackpad

I would like to buy a Apple Laptop , would it be easier to get the touchscreen feature too in that so as to i can write handwritten notes in there too comfortably , i cant buy iPad and Apple laptop both for this to be fulfilled as its too expensive so is there any other way for college notes and code stuff ?

Comment: Whats the exact question? If we know, whether future Apple Laptops will have Touchscreen capability? then the answer is, no, we dont know.

Comment: No i mean for now what can i do